# How to force Team Foundation Server SDK / API check-in to a given date?

Tags: tfs, sdk

I would like to force the date of the check-in in TFS. Is there any way?

I got the following code, but could not find any way to pass a check-in date:

```
Dim tfsChangeSet = tfsVersionControl.Workspace.CheckIn(tfsPendingChanges,
                                                       user,
                                                       tfsComment,
                                                       tfsNote,
                                                       Nothing,
                                                       Nothing)
```

Comment: Are you looking for a "wait until some date" feature or are you looking to fudge a *past* check-in date?

Comment: I am writing an import utility from svn 2 tfs, so I am needing a reproduce past commits to tfs. So I am looking to fudge a past check-in date

Comment: Use the TFS Integration / Migration toolkit: http://www.codeplex.com/TFSIntegration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible.  Checkin Date is determined by the server.  Best you can do is dynamically adjust the clock on the server machine, but that's highly unsupported.  If you change it in such a way that TFS's internal assumptions are no longer valid, you might render the database unusable.

Comment: Then why does the tf.exe command line tool allow a date to be specified as an argument to the checkin subcommand?

Comment: It does?  C:\Users\rberg> tf checkin -?
TF - Team Foundation Version Control Tool
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Commits pending changes in the current workspace to Team Foundation version
control.

tf checkin [/author:author name] [/comment:("comment"|@commentfile)]
           [/noprompt] [/notes:("Note Name"="note text"|@notefile)]
           [/override:(reason|@reasonfile)] [/recursive] [/saved] [/validate]
           [itemspec]

Comment: Mistaken.  I just came here to withdraw and you've already responded.  Sorry.